# Конструкции с "с учетом"

Tags: пунктуация

Нужно ли указанные запятые?

Именно 2015 год (,) с учетом проблем с финансированием, локализацией, импортозамещением, ценами (,)должен показать, кто и чего стоит на арматурном рынке.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Да, нужны. Оборот очень распространенный.

Стилистически коряво: "С учётом проблем С финансированием..." Нанизывание падежей.

Может быть, "учитывая проблемы"? И с запятыми вопрос сразу отпадает.

Comment: Это ведь обстоятельство: должен показать как? С учетом проблем с финансированием, локализацией, импортозамещением, ценами... Но здесь как бы уточнение, и запятые ставятся поэтому?

Comment: Он же в середине, поэтому обособление необходимо. Иначе получится, что год что-то учитывает.

Answer (score 1):

Здесь проблема не запятых: не совсем удачен порядок слов (подлежащее со сказуемым разделены длинным перечислением), "учёт" отнесен к году (= год учтёт проблемы и покажет), а из фрагментов разных выражений "кто есть кто" и "кто чего стоит" получилось нескладное третье (в него через "и" встроено непонятное "кто стОит на рынке"). Можно как-то так подправить:

В обстановке проблем с финансированием, локализацией, импортозамещением и ценами именно 2015 год должен показать, (кто есть кто и) кто чего стоит на арматурном рынке.

Если же важно применить "с учётом", то "*С учетом* такой-то ситуации, *можно предположить*, что 2015 год покажет..."